# Sed capture group not working

Tags: regex, bash, sed, regex-group

This seems like one of the sipmlest possible examples of a `sed` capture group, and it doesn't work. I've tested the regex in online regex testers, and does what I want. At the linux command line it does not.

```
$ echo "a 10 b 12" | sed -E -n 's/a ([0-9]+)/\1/p'
$
```

and

```
$ echo "a 10 b 12" | sed -E -n 's/a ([0-9]+)/\1/p'
10 b 12
```

https://regex101.com/r/WS3lG9/1

I would expect the "10" to be captured.

Comment: It does capture `10`. When dealing with sed capturing groups you should consider the whole line not a part of it

Comment: It captures 10 and replaces it with 10, the rest of the line is not matched and remains the same.

Comment: Also why do you have two identical commands with different output?

Comment: `I've tested the regex in online regex testers` - there's one of your problems. Those things are worthless since every tool supports different regexp flavors and has their own additional constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `sed` pattern is not matching complete line as it is not consuming remaining string after your match i.e. `a [0-9]+`. That's the reason you see remaining text in output.

You can use:

```
echo "a 10 b 12" | sed -E -n 's/a ([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
10
```

Or just:

```
echo "a 10 b 12" | sed -E 's/a ([0-9]+).*/\1/'
10
```

Comment: Yeah, I've never really gotten ahold of when you need to match extra stuff. Are there some good rules for that? Why does the regex tester not mind?

Comment: The thing is you're using `sed` for substitute or replace. [If you do same on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WS3lG9/2) then you will need to match till end using `.*` there also.

Comment: @abalter the rule is - when you need it do it, and when you don't need it don't do it. In this case you want sed to replace a whole line with the number `10` so, of course, you need to write a regexp that matches the whole line. `a ([0-9]+)` does NOT match the whole line `a 10 b 12` it only matches `a 10`, whereas the regexp `a ([0-9]+).*` DOES match the whole line.

Comment: That's a great explanation. I always forget to think about printing the capture group as a substitution. Makes total sense.

Comment: Having said that, you can use a gnu-grep command to achieve this using `echo "a 10 b 12" | grep -Po 'a \K[0-9]+'` (`\K` will reset the match)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of substituting the string with `sed` you could use `grep` to fish out the match

```
echo "a 10 b 12" | grep -Po '(?<=a )\d+'
```